# NoClassDefFoundError with Mapsforge 0.4.0 and Eclipse, cannot build

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mapsforge

I am trying to setup a new Android project with Mapsforge. I know that people have been getting this issue because the library requires Java 7 to build. However, I am using Build-Tools verson 20, which uses Java 7. I also have the latest updated version of the Eclipse tools. In fact, I am on a clean install of the Android Developer Kit.

So far, I have imported mapsforge-core, mapsforge-map, mapsforge-map-android, mapsforge-map-awt, and mapsforge-map-reader. 
I then tried to initialize a MapView using the following code:

```
AndroidGraphicFactory.createInstance(thisApp);
```

This results in the following error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.mapsforge.map.android.graphics.AndroidGraphicFactory
```

I looked in the referenced libraries, and the AndroidGraphicFactory class is defined within `org.mapsforge.map.android.graphics` and shows up. When looking at the jar file within `/bin/dexedLibs\`, the classes.dex file exists, but there is next to nothing else.

I followed the steps suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587939/noclassdeffounderror-with-mapsforge-0-4-0-and-eclipse), but the error persists.

Any ideas as to why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need put the jar file into the ***libs/*** folder insted of add reference on java build path.