# Mapsforge Android app example: NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mapsforge

I am attempting to run "A very basic Android app example" from [Mapsforge](http://mapsforge.org/docs/0.5.0/md_docs_Getting-Started-Android-App.html)

I'm using Eclipse. Android SDK tools are above version 19.

I have done the following:
I downloaded the jar files and placed them in the libs/ folder

- mapsforge-core-0.5.0.jar
- mapsforge-map-0.5.0.jar
- mapsforge-map-android-0.5.0.jar

My project is compiling just fine but when it runs I get the NoClassDefFoundError. 
I've been searching for an answer. I've tried adding the jars to the build path and tried to follow the suggestion [How to fix the “NoClassDefFoundError” with ADT 17](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17) and [NoClassDefFoundError with Mapsforge 0.4.0 and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587939/noclassdeffounderror-with-mapsforge-0-4-0-and-eclipse).
Nothing helped.

Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance!

The content of the MainActivity.java:

```
// name of the map file
private static final String MAPFILE = "austria.map";

private MapView mapView;        
private TileCache tileCache;
private TileRendererLayer tileRendererLayer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidGraphicFactory.createInstance(this.getApplication());

        this.mapView = new MapView(this);
        setContentView(this.mapView);

        this.mapView.setClickable(true);
        this.mapView.getMapScaleBar().setVisible(true);
        this.mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        this.mapView.getMapZoomControls().setZoomLevelMin((byte) 10);
        this.mapView.getMapZoomControls().setZoomLevelMax((byte) 20);

        this.tileCache = AndroidUtil.createTileCache(this, "mapcache",
                        mapView.getModel().displayModel.getTileSize(), 1f, 
                        this.mapView.getModel().frameBufferModel.getOverdrawFactor());
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        this.mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition.setCenter(new LatLong(48.120539, 16.269245));
        this.mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition.setZoomLevel((byte) 12);  

        tileRendererLayer.setMapFile(getMapFile());
        tileRendererLayer.setXmlRenderTheme(InternalRenderTheme.OSMARENDER);

        this.mapView.getLayerManager().getLayers().add(tileRendererLayer);   

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        this.mapView.getLayerManager().getLayers().remove(this.tileRendererLayer);
        this.tileRendererLayer.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.tileCache.destroy();
        this.mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition.destroy();
        this.mapView.destroy();
        AndroidResourceBitmap.clearResourceBitmaps();
}

private File getMapFile() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), MAPFILE);
        return file;
}
```

My LogCat:

```
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027): Process: com.example.mapsforgetest, PID: 29027
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/mapsforge/map/reader/MapDatabase;
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at org.mapsforge.map.layer.renderer.TileRendererLayer.<init>(TileRendererLayer.java:54)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at com.example.mapsforgetest.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:67)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.mapsforge.map.reader.MapDatabase" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mapsforgetest-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    ... 15 more
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mapsforge.map.reader.MapDatabase
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):        ... 16 more
01-17 10:59:33.759: E/AndroidRuntime(29027):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapsforge doesn't seem to do a very good job of explaining which libraries are actually required to get it working. I had the same issue, and your problem is just that you don't have all of the required dependencies installed.

Even though you're not directly using classes from **mapsforge-map-reader-0.5.0.jar**, it *is* a dependency of the TileRendererLayer class in mapsforge-map-0.5.0.jar. You'll see this if you pop into the [source code](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/8f49839bb9a9ee963865de789ccee02c3aba22c9/mapsforge-map/src/main/java/org/mapsforge/map/layer/renderer/TileRendererLayer.java) of TileRendererLayer.java at line 54. Line 29 lists the import for the MapDatabase class, which is what's throwing the exception.

I think your example will run fine without the other two installable libraries, which are mapsforge-map-writer-0.5.0.jar and mapsforge-map-awt-0.5.0.jar. Including them could benefit you in the future, if you eventually have to use those classes too, but mapsforge-map-writer-0.5.0.jar seems to be a little wonky (it includes classes both from the writer package and the core package). Compiling them yourself would probably be a better option.

All of the library files are available in the same place as the first three, the [CI server (release 0.5.0)](http://ci.mapsforge.org/job/release-0.5.0/). Once you add them as libraries the same way you added the others, you shouldn't have any trouble here.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the solution. But now I stumbled into another problem. It is the reason why I originally had removed mapsforge-map-writer-0.5.0.jar and mapsforge-map-awt-0.5.0.jar. Now when I attempt to run the app I get the following message in console: **Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/mapsforge/core/graphics/Align**. There are several solutions for similar problems on stackoverflow. Seems to be some build path problem. Perhaps I can find a solution.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just checked the build of mapsforge-map-writer-0.5.0.jar that I downloaded from the build server, and it has org.mapsforge.core definitions in it! The source code suggests that this shouldn't be happening. The writer jar's core classes seem to be identical to those in the actual core jar. It looks like you have two options: you can remove the writer jar, or you can just remove the core job and let the writer jar take care of it. You could also, of course, just compile the writer jar for yourself. I'll edit my answer to reflect this revelation.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. To summarize what I tried so far: Having all the jars in the libs folder throws the "Multiple dex files define" error. After removing the writer jar and leaving core jar or vice versa i get the original error message. Concerning compiling the jars for myself, I stumbled into some maven problems and so on.

Comment: @TimothyAveni hello, I'm having the same issue with getMapFile() but with 0.5.1 and I followed your fix which doesn't seem to be working. Would you have any other ideas on what should be done? I am using Android Studio, I have the jars in libs and I used gradle.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that I occasionally have problems putting jars in the libs/ folder and have to actually specify the exact names of the libraries in my gradle build file, but I think this is probably just a personal configuration issue I'm overlooking. Try unpacking the jars you're using to see which packages are actually included in them.

Answer (score 0):

At the End this had worked in my case:

Place the following jars in libs/ folder:

```
  mapsforge-core-0.5.0.jar
  mapsforge-map-0.5.0.jar
  mapsforge-map-android-0.5.0.jar
  mapsforge-map-awt-0.5.0.jar
  mapsforge-map-reader-0.5.0.jar
```

Add them to the build path (In Eclipse right click on jar -> add to build path)

Finally I din't have to compile any jar for myself. Only had to remove the writer jar and use instead the reader jar. I should have read the LocCat more carefully: "Failed resolution of: Lorg/mapsforge/map/reader/MapDatabase"

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/mapsforge/map/reader/MapDatabase;

It says, that you need mapsforge-map-reader library.

Full list of libraries that you need, you can see [here](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Developers.md#components)

For android app you need:

1. mapsforge-core
2. mapsforge-map
3. mapsforge-map-reader
4. kXML2
5. mapsforge-map-android
6. androidsvg